# OutOfMemoryException using RDLC, LocalReport, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms in ASP.NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net, iis, out-of-memory

In my Production environment, in THE SAME IIS Server, I have 2 applications

> v1 App, vS 2008 , .NET 3.5 ) , https://server/v1/Ventas.aspx  Works
>   fine using Local Report (RDLC)
>
> v2 App (VS 2012, .NET 4.5.1)  (https://server/v2/Ventas.aspx gets
>   OutOfMemoryException error using Local Report (RDLC)

Pool for ecah application:

> v1 ->APPPOOL "xxx2001Pool"
>   (MgdVersion:v2.0,MgdMode:Classic,state:Started) Account:
>   domain\MyAppPool
>
> v2 ->APPPOOL "xxx2015Pool"
>   (MgdVersion:v4.0,MgdMode:Classic,state:Started). Account:
>   ApplicationPoolIdentity. ( I try too with NETWORK SERVICE)

I dont know which is the problema: IIS config, pool, site, web.config, HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);??

The same code for v1 and v2

```
public class InformeVentas : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport
        {
            ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Informes/InformeVentas.rdlc")
        };

        List<TablaEvolucionValorAnterior> listaPolizas = DatosGrafica.GetTablaEvolucionPolizasVentas(Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["empresa"]), Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["mediador"]));
        ReportDataSource reportDataSourcePolizas = new ReportDataSource("TablaEvolucionVentasPolizas", listaPolizas);
        localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSourcePolizas);

        List<TablaEvolucionValorAnterior> listaPrimas = DatosGrafica.GetTablaEvolucionPrimasVentas(Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["empresa"]), Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["mediador"]));
        ReportDataSource reportDataSourcePrimas = new ReportDataSource("TablaEvolucionVentasPrimas", listaPrimas);
        localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSourcePrimas);

        List<TablaRamosVentas> listaRamos = DatosGrafica.GetTablaRamosVentas(Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["empresa"]), Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["mediador"]));
        ReportDataSource reportDataSourceRamos = new ReportDataSource("TablaRamosVentas", listaRamos);
        localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSourceRamos);

        List<ReportParameter> parameters = new List<ReportParameter>
        {
            new ReportParameter("FechaDatos", DatosGrafica.GetFechaActualizacionDatos().ToShortDateString())
        };
        localReport.SetParameters(parameters);

        Informe.GeneraInforme((TipoSalida)Convert.ToInt32(context.Request["tipoSalida"]), localReport, "InformeVentas");
    }

    public static void GeneraInforme(TipoSalida tipoSalida, LocalReport localReport, string tituloInforme)
    {
        string reportType = tipoSalida.ToString();

        string mimeType;

        string encoding;

        string fileNameExtension;

        Warning[] warnings;

        string[] streams;

        string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><SimplePageHeaders>False</SimplePageHeaders></DeviceInfo>";

        byte[] renderedBytes = localReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

        switch (tipoSalida)
        {
            case TipoSalida.Pdf:
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                break;
            case TipoSalida.Excel:
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                break;
        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + tituloInforme + "." + fileNameExtension);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

any suggestions for troubleshooting? it is Production environment.

**Updated**

> TODO: investigate troubleshooting can custom CAS security settings in
>   separated AppDomain directly in original application, and implement a
>   very simple AppDomain recycle policy just to contain memory leaks. For
>   more information, please refer to Vladimir’s workaround in this thread
>   Slow Performance with Dynamic Grouping and ReportViewer In Local Mode

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae/slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode?forum=sqlreportingservices

I try this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae/slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode?forum=sqlreportingservices

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b35bf409-4d73-4506-b13b-2629b1216773/reportviewer-in-net-4-even-possible-legacycasmodeltrue-causes-problems

http://blogs.msdn.com/brianhartman/archive/2010/02/18/expression-evaluation-in-local-mode.aspx

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/527451/ms-report-viewer-memory-leak-any-update-fix-winforms-application

I try

```
var sec=new System.Security.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);

localReport.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(sec);
```

and `localReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain`

but in Production Environment, I gets the same error `OutOfMemory`.

Comment: ***TODO***: `investigate troubleshooting` can custom CAS security settings in separated AppDomain directly in original application, and implement a very simple AppDomain recycle policy just to contain memory leaks. For more information, please refer to Vladimir’s workaround in this thread **`Slow Performance with Dynamic Grouping and ReportViewer In Local Mode`** ***https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae/slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode?forum=sqlreportingservices***

Comment: ***Microsoft*** **hasn't answer** _https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c8998320-14b3-48ba-8e95-2151e64164b9/use-custom-objects-for-rdl-ssrs-reporting-services?forum=sqlreportingservices_